# How to delete all text & voice channels in a discord server with discord.py with one command?

Tags: discord.py

I need to make a command to delete every channel (text and voice) in a discord server with discord.py. Can someone provide me with the code to do this. Right now i have this, which only deletes text channels. How do i make it for both at the same time?

```
@bot.command(name="deleteall")
async def delete_channels(context):
    [await channel.delete() 
    for channel in context.guild.text_channels]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an oddly destructive command, you should be careful with its use and definitely add permissions checks.

To delete the voice channels, you'd just repeat the code you've already written, but just use the `voice_channels` list.
e.g.

```
[await channel.delete() for voiceChannel in context.guild.voice_channels]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def delchannels(ctx):
   for c in ctx.guild.channels: # iterating through each guild channel
      await c.delete()
```

You can also vary this specifically for text channels or voice channels using:

```
@bot.command()
async def delchannel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
   await channel.delete()
```

And alter the argument type for specific channel types: "VoiceChannel" or "CategoryChannel".